# I have a pseudocode, but can't code yet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

thank you and sorry for my incredibly unexperienced question in advance. So, I want to make a code and I know what I want it to do, I just don't know how to program. What I need is:

function GenPre()
  1.- delete range Presupuesto!A12:C42
  2.- copy range  Imp!A2:Imp!C33  VALUES in Presupuesto!A12:Presupuesto!C42 (Imp cells are formulas, and I want to copy just the values)
  3.- show only used rows in column A in Presupuesto!A12:A42 (consider some rows     will be already hidden, so unhiding them first would be an idea)
  4.- go to sheet Presupuesto (once I do this function, I want to end up on the sheet Presupuesto
end Generar

This function will be runned by a button in another sheet in the same spreadsheet.

and so far, I have this:

```
function GenPre() {  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetbyname(Presupuesto);
//next step is to select and delete the content of the range on the sheet
}
```

I know I'm asking for much, I just can't find much about selecting defined cells... and I really don't know how to program yet.

Thanks a bunch!!

Edit

So, I started tweaking with what k4k4sh1 answered and got this (AND reading other posts on hiding rows containing "x" on a given cell):

```
function GenPre() {

  var sheetp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Presupuesto') //name a variable to the sheet where we're pasting information
  var sheetc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Imp')         //name a variable to the sheet frome where we're copying information
  sheetp.getRange('a12:c41').clearContent()                                        //delete all values in the range where we're copying
  sheetc.getRange('A2:C31').copyValuesToRange(sheetp,1,3,12,41);                    //copy from source range to destination range
  sheetp.showRows(12,41);                                                          //make sure all rows in the destination range are shown
  for( i=12 ; i<=41 ; i++) { 
       if (sheetp.getRange('A'+i).getValue() == '') { // status == ''
         sheetp.hideRows(i);
       } 
   }
}
```

Te script is running how it should, but now, I want it to run faster (takes 12 seconds to run, when it doesn't really look that heavy), and is there a function to switch my view to sheetp? thank you all!

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking us to do all the work :)
Let's start from your piece of code:
the method `.getSheetByName(shName)` accepts a string as argument, so you should change it to
 
`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Presupuesto');`.
Mind that JavaScript is case-sensitive, so `.getSheetbyname` is not the same as `.getSheetByName()`.
According to [Sheet Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) use `sheet.getRange()` to get your Range Object. Take a look to [Range Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range): to clear the range content including formats use `.clear()`, to clear just the content leaving the formatting intact use `.clearContent()`.
To hide unused rows try:

```
function hideRows(sheetName, column) {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());
    s.getRange(column)
        .getValues()
        .forEach(function (r, i) {
            if (r[0] == '') {s.hideRows(i + 1);}
        });
}
// hideRows('Presupuesto', 'A12:A42');
```

Comment: k4ksh1, this is code gold for me, I'll get to work with this and if it's not enough, will post a question that doesn't look as bad as this one. This is EXACTLY what I need (something to get me started).

Comment: Don't worry about it: if you get stuck again post your code and we'll get through that!

Comment: I actually got it to work, but it's running quite slow. After your guidance, I found inspiration and did a lot, it's just running too slow. (makes each command in about .3 seconds), so I´m gonna try and hide all the rows with one command, just need to find out how. Thanks!!